# Greyed out shaders on linked asset. I can't animate shaders

Tags: node-editor, asset, library

This one is about Asset Library creations

I have a car where the brake lights are animated using a shader (it's a mix2color connecting 2 diferent textures. I want to animate the Factor to switch between one another)

I have added the car to my asset library and imported it to another scene *as Linked*. Then I've  overriden it so I can animate it's armature, but all the materials and shader nodes are greyed out so I can't animate the brake lights.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

On the original scene where I created the car I've added a custom property that drives the MixColor factor.

The idea is going back to the scene where the car is referenced to, and even if the shaders are still greyed out, I can still animate this property.
However, I found that the property itself was also greyed out. When hovering the mouse on it a message appears:

'Can't edit this property from an override data-block'

The way to solve this is finding the object that contains the property and make it local as follows:

[image: Make local]